# How to show related object popup when the user clicks on selected autocomplete field options in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I want to show the standard related object popup when the user clicks on a selected option in a Django admin autocomplete multi-select field, like it works when clicking the `ForeignKey` field pencil icon .

The models are as follows:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=160)

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, verbose_name=_('authors'), blank=True)
    ...
```

Is it possible to do this by extending Django admin?

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding the required custom HTML was easier using the `ModelSelect2Multiple` widget from [*django-autocomplete-light*](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) (DAL).

The admin configuration is as follows:

```py
from dal import autocomplete

@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = [
          '/static/books/js/book-admin.js',
          # other required JS files, see https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/1143#issuecomment-632755326
        ]

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'authors':
            return forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                required=False,
                label=Author._meta.verbose_name_plural.title(),
                queryset=Author.objects.all(),
                widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                    url='author-autocomplete',
                    attrs={'data-html': True}))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The DAL view is as follows:

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from dal import autocomplete

from .models import Author
from django.urls import reverse


class AuthorAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Author.objects.none()

        qs = Author.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs

    def get_selected_result_label(self, item):
        change_url = reverse('admin:books_author_change', kwargs={'object_id': item.id})
        return mark_safe('<span onclick="event.stopPropagation(); showRelatedObjectPopup({'
                         f"href: '{change_url}?_popup=1', id: 'change_id_author'"
                         f'}})">{item.name}</span>')
```

When selecting a new author in the *Authors* field in the *Book* change view in admin, the HTML element is managed by `ModelSelect2Multiple`, so the custom HTML is present and clicking on the newly selected author opens the popup as intended. But the custom HTML will not be present in existing selections, so the click handlers have to be added with jQuery in `book-admin.js`:

```js
'use strict';

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /**
     * Show related object popup when user clicks on selected author name.
     */
    (function ($) {
        var $authorsSelect2Selections = $('div.form-row.field-authors .select2-selection__choice > span:nth-child(2)');
        var $authorOptions = $('#id_authors > option');
        $authorsSelect2Selections.click(function ($event) {
            $event.stopPropagation();
            var self = this;
            // Find corresponding option by text comparison, assuming that author name is unique
            var $result = $authorOptions.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text() === self.textContent;
            });
            showRelatedObjectPopup({
                href: '/admin/books/author/' + $result.val() + '/change/?_popup=1',
                id: 'change_id_other_authors'
            });
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
});
```

`event.stopPropagation()` prevents the Select2 dropdown from opening.

You also need to override `dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup` and `dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup` in `book-admin.js` to avoid problems, here is an incomplete version:

```js
  /**
   * Override Django related object popup dismissal functions with DAL amendments.
   * Incomplete.
   */
  (function ($) {
    function dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopupForDAL(win, objId, newRepr, newId) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(win.name);
      if (elem && elem.options && elem.dataset.autocompleteLightUrl) { // this is a DAL element
        $(elem.options).each(function () {
          if (this.value === objId) {
            this.textContent = newRepr;
            // this.value = newId;
          }
        });
        // FIXME: trigger('change') does not update the element as it should and removes popup code
        // $(elem).trigger('change');
        win.close();
      } else {
        dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopupOriginal(win, objId, newRepr, newId);
      }
    }

    window.dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopupOriginal = window.dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup;
    window.dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup = dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopupForDAL;

    function dismissAddRelatedObjectPopupForDAL(win, newId, newRepr) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(win.name);
      if (elem && elem.options && elem.dataset.autocompleteLightUrl) { // this is a DAL element
        elem.options[elem.options.length] = new Option(newRepr, newId, true, true);
        // FIXME: trigger('change') adds the new element, but removes popup code
        $(elem).trigger('change');
        win.close();
      } else {
        dismissAddRelatedObjectPopupOriginal(win, newId, newRepr);
      }
    }

    window.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopupOriginal = window.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup
    window.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup = dismissAddRelatedObjectPopupForDAL
  })(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: See also discussion in django-developers mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/cvE6TNkZLVQ